# Symfony roleHierarchy and controller security annotation

Tags: symfony

I have a role hierarchy defined in my security.yml config file :

```
role hierarchy:        
    ROLE_USER: [ROLE_USER]  
    ROLE_OFFICE: [ROLE_OFFICE]  
    ROLE_TEST: [ROLE_OFFICE, ROLE_USER]
```

I want to use the security annotations in my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/office", name="office")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_OFFICE')")
 */
```

How can i use the role hierarchy with annotation. With my example, a user with ROLE_TEST will not be allowed to access my office route.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you defining new role, you're defining from which existing role(s) will the role inherit. Your definition here is wrong.

1. You don't have to define `ROLE_USER`, it will be defined once you extend it. (thanks to @Yonel)
2. As I mentioned above, new role should extend existing one:

   ```
   role_hierarchy:
       ROLE_OFFICE: ROLE_USER  
       ...
   ```

   `ROLE_OFFICE` will also have the `ROLE_USER`
3. Your `ROLE_TEST` now has also `ROLE_OFFICE`, this means that `ROLE_TEST` is allowed to access route /office. To fix this, you have to remove `ROLE_OFFICE` from your definition.

---

This should be working definition:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_OFFICE: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_TEST: ROLE_USER
```

---

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles

Comment: Just say that `ROLE_USER` is not defined by Symfony itself, it's defined in `role_hierarchy` (i.e. `ROLE_OFFICE: ROLE_USER` defines both roles simultaneously)

Comment: @Yonel Thanks, I didn't know that! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this precision. Now my security annotation is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you change a little bit your annotation by :

```
@Security("is_granted('ROLE_OFFICE')")
```

Does the ROLE_TEST access the ressource?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude a route to a specific role you can negate the condition. As Example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/office", name="office")
 * @Security("not has_role('ROLE_TEST')")
 */
```

Hope this help